# Save image to temp dir and open it

Tags: java, android

I'd like to save a bitmap in temp dir and open it in default image viewer app.

So I try:

```
   File outputDir = this.getCacheDir(); // context being the Activity pointer
    File outputFile = File.createTempFile(name, ".png", outputDir);
    OutputStream fos2;
    fos2 = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    saved = bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos2);

    if(saved) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(outputFile);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + imageUri), "image/*");
            startActivity(intent);
    }
```

The problem is the image is not open, maybe something wrong with the imageUri path?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `Uri.fromFile()` has been banned, in effect, since Android 7.0. Normally, your attempt to us it with an `Intent` would crash with a `FileUriExposedException`. Apparently, you decided to try to bypass the check. However, *nobody else has to honor your `file:///` `Uri`*, because, again, that has been banned for years. Please switch to `FileProvider`.

Second, you are using `"image/*"` as an outbound MIME type. It is *your* content, so it is *your* job to tell the recipient what file format it is. And, since you know that it is a PNG, use `image/png`, not `image/*`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Oh, thats why when I am in api 19  `intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + imageDir), "image/png");` works, but not api 25... So should I use FileProvider even if I use temp dir?

Comment: @RGS: Yes. Not only will it not work on Android 7.0 for the `file://` `Uri` reason, but no apps other than yours has access to that file. `getCacheDir()` is private to your app -- it is not some system-wide temp directory (which Android does not really have).